# W(a,b,x)=x＋(a－b)x^2/2!＋(a－b)(a－2b)x^3/3!＋...

Tags: special-functions

Given

$W(a,b,x)=x＋(a－b)x^2/2!＋(a－b)(a－2b)x^3/3!＋...$ and $Abs(x)＜1/(Abs(b))$

Prove:

if $x=W(a,b,y)$ then $y=W(a,b,x)$

Comment: Please use mathjax

Comment: Have you done any work on this?  Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: Is the next coefficient supposed to be $\frac{(a-b)(a-2b)(a-3b)}{4!}?$

Comment: @saulspatz sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get that the result is true
only if $a=b$
in which case
$W(a, b, x) = x$.

Note that
if $a=2b$
then
$W(x) = x+bx^2/2$
so

$\begin{array}\\
W(W(x))
&=W(x)+bW(x)^2/2\\
&=x+bx^2/2+b(x+bx^2/2)^2/2\\
&=x+bx^2/2+b(x^2+bx^3+b^2x^4/4)/2\\
&=x+bx^2+b^2x^3/2+b^3x^4/8\\
&\ne x\\
\end{array}
$

Let's see what $W$ is.

$\begin{array}\\
W(a, b, x)
&=W(x)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(a-kb)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^nb^{n-1}}{n!}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(\dfrac{a}{b}-k)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^nb^{n-1}}{n!}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(r-k)
\qquad r = \dfrac{a}{b}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^nb^{n-1}}{rn!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(r-k)\\
&=\dfrac1{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^nb^{n}\binom{r}{n}\\
&=\dfrac1{a}(-1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^nb^{n}\binom{r}{n})\\
&=\dfrac1{a}(-1+(1+bx)^r)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
W(W(y))
&=\dfrac1{a}(-1+(1+bW(y))^r)\\
&=\dfrac1{a}(-1+(1+\dfrac{b}{a}(-1+(1+by)^r))^r)\\
&=\dfrac1{a}(-1+(1-\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{b}{a}(1+by)^r)^r)\\
\end{array}
$

You claim that
this is $y$.

This means that
$ay+1
=(1-\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{b}{a}(1+by)^r)^r
=\dfrac1{a^r}(a-b+b(1+by)^r)^r
$
or
$a^r(ay+1)
=(a-b+b(1+by)^r)^r
$.

If $y=0$,
both sides are $a^r$.

Otherwise
the derivative of
the left side 
with respect to $y$
is
$a^{r+1}$
and that of the right side is
$(b(1+by)^r)'(a-b+b(1+by)^r)^{r-1}
=b^2(1+by)^{r-1}(a-b+b(1+by)^r)^{r-1}
$
which is definitely not the same.

In particular,
that at $0$ is
$b^2a^{r-1}
$
which is not the same
unless $a=b$.

If $a=b$,
then $r=1$
so that
$(a-b+b(1+by)^r)^r
=(b(1+by)^r)^r
=b(1+by)
$
so the two expressions
are equal.

(I'm the editor.Thanks for your answer.By the way,can you suggest some books about special-functions?)

Comment: Search Amazon for "Special Functions" and you get a number of good choices, including two from Dover available for $10 to $15 and in Kindle editions.

Comment: How about Special Functions written by Z.X Wang and D.R Guo?

Comment: That too. Actually, if you have the money, I would recommend the one by George E. Andrews and Richard Askey.